# Горизонтальное центрирование блока неизвестной ширины в более узком блоке

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Проще говоря, как отцентировать тултип, который больше родительского блока? Ширина тултипа неизвестна, определяется количеством текста. Может быть больше блока.

Мой текущий вариант: http://jsfiddle.net/uU882/
Я использую оберточный слой, который делаю заведомо большим, чем сам тултип, и внутри делаю text-align: center; Но это не очень хороший вариант, поскольку этот оберточный слой пораждает горизонтальные скроллы, если блок близко к краю страницы. Если блок - ссылка, то получается очень большая область кликабельности и прочие проблемы.

Обсчитать полученную ширину JS`ом и отцентриовать через left: 50% с уже известной шириной - вариант, но JS хотелось бы избежать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если забить на старые браузеры, то вот так: http://jsfiddle.net/uU882/1/
В противном случае только JS

Comment: Отличная идея, спасибо :)